# Ignore the image cache on setImage:

Tags: uiimageview, cache-control

I have the following code

```
NSString *myPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"../Documents/%@",@"bla.png"];
[imgView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:myPath]];    // works fine
[self updateMyImage:[UIImage imageNamed:myPath]];  // loads another image as bla.png (works fine)
[imgView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:myPath]];    // displays the old image, *not* the new one
```

The image is loaded in updateMyImage: (I open it (from the simulator's *disk*) and it is the "**new**" one)
but imgView displays the "**old**" one. I guess its a cache issue. Since the iOS has loaded the `[UIImage imageNamed:@"bla.png"]`
once, it thinks that this is the same one. How can I "flush" the cache and tell it to reload the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setImage: loads (*as you corectly guess*) from the cache.
Look for it in the 'UIImage Class Reference' *(on xcode's Organizer window)*

Few lines down it *gives* you the answer: use the initWithContentsOfFile: method.
So, after you change the image do this:

```
 NSString *myAbsolutePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0],@"bla.png"]];
 UIImage *myImg = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:myAbsolutePath];
 [imgView setImage:myImg];
```

and now imgView will have the new image (as long as a img file exists at myAbsolutePath).